# Не получается достать сообщение

Tags: python, json

Почему у меня вылезает ошибка, когда я хочу достать значение? Самое интересное, что оно иногда работает, а иногда нет. В чем может бы[image: введите сюда описание изображения]ть проблема?

Comment: Значит иногда там словарь, а иногда список. Или иногда туда ход не доходит.

Comment: список и ключи там одни и те же только значения разные

Comment: @Axel А Вы проверьте это. Перед ошибочной строкой печатайте `data_city`

Comment: щас попользовался, мне кажется дело с апишником, после нного кол-ва запросов, data просто ничего не выводит-пусто, пройдет время все нормально. может в этом проблема?